# Browse for an image on an iPad/iPhone from HTML5

Tags: ipad, canvas, gallery, html5-canvas

I have an HTML5 application that allows users to drag-n-drop an image to a canvas, or alternatively, browse for it on their local disk. Once I got the image, I display it in the canvas using `context.drawImage()`. Got all the kinks out and it works great.
BUT. Now my customer want to use it on an iPad. Drag-n-drop is out of the question (the browser is a full window on iDevices). But the browse functionality, which is basically an input of type file, doesn't work either.

To clarify, the behavior I need is selecting an image from the gallery and displaying it in a canvas.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You may find these answers helpful. http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-help/14830-new-ipad-owner-distress-photos-file-browsing-ftp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no satisfying answers for this.

http://learnbythedrop.com/forum/iphoneipad-safari-image-upload-resrictions

Basically, mobile safari is pretty severely sandboxed – file uploads don't work, can't grab files from photos, etc.

With iOS 5 there may be a solution for this using iCloud. Content is stored and pushed to mobile devices. Perhaps you'll be able to access the image from your photo stream?

Alternately, you could use a service like photo bucket or flickr to store your images, then use the API to access them from your page.

Comment: Guess I can't do it then. And forcing people to upload an image to "the cloud" and then getting the URL to that image is not really a good workaround, but I guess it'll have to do now. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed – it's not an optimal solution. Unfortunately you're dealing with all sorts of sandboxing issues. That said, you could always create an app with, for instance, phone gap and a little objective-c.